# mysql copy from one table column to another empty table with intergrity contraints

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, relational-database

I have a table called

```
     Seats
ID   Number  Region_ID  Venue_ID


     seatreservation
ID   Flag   seat_ID    reservation_ID
```

Now the seatreservation table is empty but has reservation_ID as a foreign key to another table. So i am trying to copy the contents from Seats.ID and put it in seatreservation.seat_ID  where for example Region_ID is =2. If i use an insert statement 
like  :

`INSERT INTO seatreservation (seat_ID) SELECT ID FROM seat WHERE venue_ID = 2;`

It wont work because reservation_ID on seatreservation cannot be null(referential integrity). Is there a way to fill the seat_ID column from Seats.ID while also inserting for example "1" for all reservation_IDs in the loop to avoid null ? I need help in extending the sql statement or another approach please.

Answer (score 4):

```
INSERT INTO seatreservation (seat_ID, reservation_ID) 
SELECT ID, 1 FROM seat WHERE venue_ID = 2;
```

Comment: You Mr Shibormot are a life saver ! Thank you.

Comment: So for example if i want to add an additional field and enter :Available as value can i do something like this ?

INSERT INTO seatreservation (seat_ID, reservation_ID,Flag) 
SELECT ID, 1 'Available' FROM seat WHERE venue_ID = 2;

But its not working. Please explain your query to me and how the parser can interpret that 1 value is for reservation but cant interpret Available string for Flag.

Comment: @FrankSMallville, what type is your `Flag` column of? And what is error message?

Comment: FLag is of type String and the error message is just a wrong sql statement.